# Avoid composer's autoload.php to parse all files

Tags: php, composer-php, php-7.4

Here is my problem: I have upgraded a complex application to PHP 7.4, and yes, I didn't test thoroughly enough.

Now I would like to run on task with an older PHP version, but it cannot parse all of my vendor files. Here is the error and the line. It's a new feature of PHP 7.4.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in .\vendor\sentry\sentry\src\functions.php on line 25

```
 function captureMessage(string $message, ?Severity $level = null): ?string
```

Until now I thought, that Composers `vendor\autoload.php` loads classes and functions in the vendor directory only on demand. Unused classes and therefore the offending files written in PHP 7.4 would not be loaded.

Unfortunately, I notice, that `require_once('./vendor/autoload.php')` is enough to see the parse error. Is it possible to configure Composer in a way, that it does not preload the vendor files, but loads them only once the classes or functions are requested ?

Comment: That *is* how Composer works, so your code is presumably using that file somewhere.

Comment: @ceejayoz No, the package in question is using the `autoload: files` directive to include the file on every page load. See my answer for details.

Comment: There are features used like `function name(): ?string` which do not run in older versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original assumption was correct: in general, the PHP autoloader only loads classes when they are used, and Composer simply provides an implementation of that autoloader.

However, Composer also includes [a feature to unconditionally load a file](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files). This is used when a package contains functions, constants, or configuration, which cannot be loaded on-demand (because PHP's autoloader only handles classes).

One of the packages you are using uses this feature, so every time you include `vendor/autoload.php`, the file it specifies is required. In the error message shown, we can see the package name `sentry/sentry`, and in [that package's `composer.json`](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/blob/master/composer.json#L56), we can see this:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "src/functions.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Sentry\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

The best way around this is probably to downgrade this dependency, and any others which include code that only runs under PHP 7.4. To do this, you can simply re-run `composer update` on your older version of PHP, and it will only pick up packages which support that version.

You can also specify [the `platform` option](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) in your `composer.json` to always request dependencies for an older PHP version, even when you are running Composer under PHP 7.4. However, there is a risk that the resulting dependencies will be incompatible with PHP 7.4.

Answer (score 1):

In your composer.json, you can add `platform` into your config, to force it to resolve dependencies to a specific version of PHP.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6"
    },
},
```